# How to code in Eclipse as fast as in VisualStudio?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2010, resharper

I am used to code in VisualStudio with Resharper. And I code fast with Resharper's auto-completion functionality. When I moved to Java and Eclipse I found out that Eclipse doesn't need a tool like Resharper, because Resharper was made so that VS could have funcionalities like Eclipse. After that I printed the list of Eclipse shortcuts and started coding.

But, it's been a month or so now and I code soooo slowly. I tried setting Eclipse intellisense (Content Assist) to open faster, but it didn't help. And the code completion is sooo slow too. For example, in VS I just select the method and resharper puts the closing bracket + semi-colon. Then, Eclipse has one shortcut for intellisense and the other for variable completion (alt+/), wtf.

What should I set in Eclipse so that I code as fast as in VS? Why Resharper+VS make me code faster that Eclipse? Am I missing some add-on or some settings?

PS. I did not intent to discredit Eclipse nor to start advocacy topic. I like Eclipse. I work in it 12h/day and I would like it to prove it's faster that VS.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at JetBrains IntelliJ. It mimics a lot of resharper stuff as they are made by the same company.

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Comment: I am aware of IntelliJ, but is there any help for Eclipse?

Answer (score 3):

ReSharper is the brainchild of JetBrains, the people who develop and sell IntelliJ.

If you want to find out what the analog of your ReSharper experience is for Java, use IntelliJ.

I used to like Eclipse, too - until I was shown IntelliJ.  That was six years ago; I haven't gone back.

Comment: I am aware of IntelliJ, but is there any help for Eclipse?

Comment: Both of you answered the question but he was the first so it's fair to mark his answer as the one.

Comment: But they haven't answered your question. They mention an alternative, I think you made a good point with this question.